# Why do I have this problem with the git bash terminal when executing an npm command?

Tags: npm, git-bash, astrojs

I attach an image and text of the problem: what happens is that, when executing an `npm` command like creating a new astro project, the `git bash` console duplicates the content.

Is there anyone who is so kind to help me or who has had this error and how to solve it?
It is on windows 10

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/acyXV.png]

```
Git Bash
Empty project
? Which template would you like to use? » - Use arrow-keys. Return to submit. 
Just the basics (recommended)
Blog
Portfolio
Documentation Site
Empty project
? Which template would you like to use? » - Use arrow-keys. Return to submit. 
Just the basics (recommended)
Blog
Portfolio
Documentation Site
Empty project
? Which template would you like to use? » - Use arrow-keys. Return to submit.
Just the basics (recommended)
Blog
Portfolio
Documentation Site
Empty project
? Which template would you like to use? » - Use arrow-keys. Return to submit.
Just the basics (recommended)
Blog
Portfolio
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the `npm` program used (probably [`withastro/astro`](https://github.com/withastro/astro) in your case).

But since `git bash` does not provide a good experience, try first the same `npm` command in a regular `CMD`, to check if the issue persists.

The [OP FrxnDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20091541/frxndev) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74002093/why-do-i-have-this-problem-with-the-git-bash-terminal-when-executing-an-npm-comm/74003427#comment130675520_74003427):

> I found the problem, and when I run the `git bash` on mintty I get that error, but if I run the `bash.exe` that is inside `/bin` that mail on CMD, I don't get that problem.

As I mentioned in the comments below, using Git `bin\bash.exe` should work indeed. That is what I suggested in "[Git Bash (mintty) is extremely slow on Windows 10 OS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43034820/6309)".

[Mintty](https://mintty.github.io/) is the Cygwin Terminal emulator, and Git for Windows does not use it, but is a [mingw64 binary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59654346/6309).

Comment: The problem is terminal of git bash, when I run the same command in the cmd terminal of windows it runs it correctly without duplicating anything. That's my problem, I don't know if anyone has had the same problem and how to solve it.

Comment: @FrxnDev I understand. Can you try and use a simplified `PATH` ([as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73391656/6309), add also the PATH for `npm`) from a CMD, and type in it: `bash`. In that bash session, does the issue persists?

Comment: I found the problem, and when I run the git bash on mintty I get that error, but if I run the bash.exe that is inside /bin that mail on CMD, I don't get that problem.

Comment: @FrxnDev Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, as well as several additional links.